# PHP curl not working but working in MacOS terminal cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am hitting `post` request with `json` body. First a tried it using MacOS Terminal and it worked.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -H "apiKey:API_KEY" -X POST -k -d '{some_json_data}'  https://portal.betterplace.co.in​/VishwasAPI/api/public/v2/aadhaar/authenticate
```

The same request is failing when I am trying it with PHP cURL as follows

```
$body = [SOME_KEY_VALUE_PAIR];
            $str = json_encode($body);
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://portal.betterplace.co.in​/VishwasAPI/api/public/v2/aadhaar/authenticate');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                    'apiKey' => 'API_KEY',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'Accept' => 'application/json']
            );
            $res = curl_exec($ch);
            echo $res;
            curl_close($ch);
```

With this I got following response :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /VishwasAPI/api/public/v2/aadhaar/authenticate on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening plz?

Comment: Turn out that php `curl` is adding space before `/VishwasAPI/api/public/v2/aadhaar/authenticate` in the URL . How to remove that.

Comment: Even after the space removal its not working. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had the same issue today, found this page (and was disappointed when I saw no reply), but then I found my solution there : [cURL + Laravel Valet + dnsmasq not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688451/curl-laravel-valet-dnsmasq-not-working)

hope you found a solution within the last 2 years ;)